# How do I remove a table’s margin if all of its rows are hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have number of dynamically created tables. Within these tables are rows of data that may or may not be hidden. Sometimes all the rows in a table are hidden. Even though they are hidden, the `<table>` still exerts its bottom margin so it still takes up space on the display.

Is there any way to hide the entire table if all the rows in the table are hidden?

Comment: This question pretty straightforward if you know HTML and CSS. Not unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a table with a class of `table--dynamic`, do

```js
$(".table--dynamic")
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).find("tr:visible").length < 1;
    })
        .hide();
```

```css
table {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table--dynamic">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table--dynamic">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```